# uiautomator dumpWindowHierarchy(...) cannot change dump directory

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am using uiautomator dumpWindowHierarchy(...) to dump a view tree of the current device display. However, it seems I cannot change the saving directory for the dumped .xml files. The code below works, but it saves .xml file to /data/local/tmp/local/tmp folder. "dumpXml" variable is just a file name, e.g. "test.xml"

```
public void dumpView(String dumpXml) {
    final File dump = new File(new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "local/tmp"), dumpXml);

    dump.mkdirs();
    if (dump.exists()) {
        dump.delete();
    }
    try {
        getUiDevice().dumpWindowHierarchy(dumpXml);
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("UI hierarchy: " + dumpXml));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        testCaseAssertion("ERROR: did not dump a view file");
    }
}
```

If I change `new File(new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "local/tmp"), dumpXml);` to a different folder, e.g.  `new File("sdcard/Test"), dumpXml);`, then I could not find the dumped .xml file.

Can someone explain me why? How can I change the saving directory of the dumped .xml file?

Comment: What string are you passing to dumpView(...)? e.g. what's the value of dumpXml?

Comment: It looks like you're creating a new directory (variable 'dump'), but you're not updating the value you pass to dumpWindowHierarchy(..)

Comment: `public void dumpWindowHierarchy (String fileName)` is deprecated.
Use `dumpWindowHierarchy(File)` or `dumpWindowHierarchy(OutputStream)` instead.

Comment: I guess dumpWindowHierarchy(File) and dumpWindowHierarchy(OutputStream) are only available for certain Android versions. I am using API 23, and it only shows dumpWindowHierarchy (String fileName) is available

Comment: a similar implementation is here: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/83db786c6ca1107affa83bfc34630559b762c028/lib/devices/android/bootstrap/src/io/appium/android/bootstrap/utils/XMLHierarchy.java#L79

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the full path to dumpWindowHierarchy(..) if you want it to end up on the SD card.

Right now you're calling dumpWindowHierarchy("test.xml") which is a relative path. By default, UI Automator will use the directory returned by [Context.getFileStreamPath(..)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)) if a full path is not specified.